# Android Tablet Application - ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

We are trying to build an Android App for Samsung Galaxy Tablets. Is there a way we can increase the height of the ActionBar? We are using Android 3.1 API 12.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can apply a custom theme to your application.

Create styles.xml in your res/values/ directory and add something like this:

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:style/Theme">
    <item name="android:actionBarSize">@dimen/action_bar_default_height</item>
</style>
```

Then create dimens.xml in your res/values/ directory and add something like this:

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="action_bar_default_height">55dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Then in your application manifest set the theme of the application like this:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:logo="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:theme="@style/CustomTheme" >
...
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a custom Action Bar.

Here is a good tutorial

[Creating a custom Action bar](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-beginner-tutorials/action-bar/)

Also here is a good example from the dev site.

[Android Action Bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however I already have a custom Action Bar with my layout, however the layout_params for the custom layout doesnt take affect because the Action Bar has the height set to 56dp. So i was looking for a way in which i can override the height to my specifications.